# basic function vs anonymous function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello guys i have follow code example:

```
 var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue!"
  },
  mounted: function() {
    function something() {
      console.log("hy");
    };
  }
});
```

Here i have the problem, when i call this function with plain javascript outside of the vue instance it says "something is not a function". 
But if i change the function to an anonymous function it works:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue!"
  },
  mounted: function() {
    something = function() {
      console.log("hy");
    };
  }
});
```

This code works totally fine. My question is: Is there a way to make the basic function making work? I need to add some code to an existing programm, and the programm wont work with the `function something(){}` declaration.

Comment: In the second example, it looks like `something` is potentially a global variable. Could that be what's happening? You can check by running `window.something()` in the console.

Comment: second works, at the first example i get error "Object doesn't support property or method 'something'"

Comment: Can i make it work with the basic declaration `function something(){}` instead of anonymous?

Comment: You're declaring a function `something` inside `mounted`, which is creating the function only within the scope of `mounted`. If you did `something()` at the end of `mounted`, the function would execute. As @TKoL mentioned, it looks like you're creating a global variable `something` which has the value of the `function`.

Why do you need to declare a function inside `mounted`?

Comment: @drarx the second is working because you're calling the function from the global context, and you've defined it globally. I don't really know what your needs or requirements are, so I don't really understand why you would want that to work, but if that is what you want to happen, then `window.something = function(){}` is probably the way to go. Again, I find it hard to give definitive advice because I don't really understand why you'd want this.

Comment: well thats a other story, because the code before is made with jquery and they collide somehow with my vue app and the only thing that worked fine is when i change all `function something(){}` to anonymous `something = function(){}`